# AngularJS GlobalCtrl vs $rootScope vs Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am confused on a couple of things with Globals in Angular. Below is my pseudo code.

1) With the way I have my GlobalCtrl placed, I am able to reference my $scope.modalOptions from all of my controllers. That being the case, I'm confused as to why I see people adding global properties to $rootScope instead of just adding them like I am doing here. Is that just in case they want to inject it into a service or something?

2) Should I be using a service instead of adding properties and methods to my GlobalCtrl? If so, why?

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="GlobalCtrl">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

```
function GlobalCtrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.modalOptions = {
        backdropFade: true,
        dialogFade: true
    };
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35411623/2893073

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The 'Main Controller' approach is definitely preferable to using $rootScope.

Scope inheritance is there, so why not leverage it. In my opinion, that solution works well for most cases, i.e. unless you need to have a parallel controller somewhere (that wouldn't be a child of Main). In that case, the best way to go is to use a service and inject it where needed. Services (or rather factories, because that's what you'll probably be using -- read more about them [here](http://iffycan.blogspot.com/2013/05/angular-service-or-factory.html)) are singletons and work well for sharing data across controllers.

### Important to know about scopes

Scope inheritance is pretty much regular JavaScript inheritance at play. You should tend to use **objects** for your data, because they are passed by reference.

If you have a primitive like `$scope.myString = 'is of a primitive data type';` in your parent controller and try to overwrite the value in a child controller, the result won't be what you'd expect -- it will create a new string on the child controller instead of writing to the parent.

Suggested reading [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

### Final thoughts

If you are using the nested controllers approach, do not forget to still inject `$scope` (and other dependencies) in the child controller. It might work without, but it's slower and hard to test, and last but not least -- the wrong way to do it.

Finally, if you have a lot of state variables to keep track of and/or a lot of usage points, it's definitely a good idea to extract them into a service.

Comment: I was starting an answer but this is pretty much what I was going to say. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3w88/) that would show a parallel controller like @finishingmove suggests (where $rootScope or preferably a service would be useful).

Comment: This blog states that `JavaScript` is not pass by reference. http://whatsthepointy.blogspot.com/2013/11/javascript-does-not-have-pass-by.html

Comment: Indeed, @KevinMeredith, in JavaScript, everything is passed by value. But the value is a reference in case of objects. This is why you can't change the referenced object itself, only its properties.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking global variables are considered bad practice, as they don't encourage encapsulation, make debugging difficult, and promote bloated code.  Here's a good discussion of global variables: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad.

A good rule of thumb is to add properties and methods to the most local scope possible and use services to share data between modules.