# angular js how can I use a collection in all of my scopes

Tags: angularjs

I have a collection that I need to access in all of my nested scopes.  Inside my directive templates, inside my directives in ng-repeat... n levels deep.  I don't want to have to say $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent....$parent.MyList.

I've tried using $rootScope, but clearly I lack the understanding of how this works.  I pass it into my directive during the declaration like so:

```
$rootScope.MyList = ["list": 1];
...
...
MyApp.directive('mydirective', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) { 
return {
   restrict:  'A',
   replace: false,
   link: function (scope, rootScope) {

}
}
}])
```

The rootScope does not contain MyList.  Is there something I'm doing wrong, or a better way to do it?  I've thought of using a Factory or Service, but I don't know how to set that up and we all know how crappy the documentation is for Angular, so searching is very frustrating.

Comment: scopes are usually nested (unless you do a {scope: true} in a directive) so you can just reference the list as `$scope.MyList` using any nested scopes (you only need the $scope.$parent to avoid collisions).  If that doesn't suffice, use the Service approach suggested by David Childs

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a plnkr or jsfiddle reproducing this behavior? I can get the controller to communicate with service using `$rootScope`.
http://plnkr.co/edit/IEhOde

However, you'd probably want to create a `service` which would cache the value that you want and inject it in your directive and retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `$rootScope.MyList = ["list": 1]` has syntax error, should be `$rootScope.MyList = ["list", 1]` or `$rootScope.MyList = [{"list": 1}]`.

Anything you assign to `$rootScope` is accessible within child `$scopes` (except isolate scopes) due to [prototype inheritance](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope).

Generally if you want to share something within whole app, you can assign it to `$rootScope` as you did or you can create top level `AppCtrl` which will have something like `$scope.MyList=...` and all nested scopes will have access to it. Second option is bit better when it comes to testability as you can inject service to `AppCtrl` which provides `MyList` data. You can see this pattern in action here [AngularJS GlobalCtrl vs $rootScope vs Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006054/angularjs-globalctrl-vs-rootscope-vs-service).

Answer (score 0):

A service/provider is the recommended approach.

For just a list of data you can use the value provider:

```
app.value('listService',  {  
   MyList : {"list": 1}
});
```

Inject it where you need it, and you can include it in the relevant scopes as such:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope,listService) {
  $scope.list = listService.MyList;
});
```

A fiddle of that:  http://jsfiddle.net/qKcQL/

Injecting it where you need is good for documentation and maintenance.  But if you really need this on the global `$rootScope` then this will accomplish that:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope,listService,$rootScope) {
   $rootScope.list = listService.MyList;
});
```

`$rootScope` fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/qKcQL/1/