# Angular use root scope vs services to share data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been reading [wrox angular book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-AngularJS.productCd-1118832078.html). Inside the book the author describes that a method of sharing data between controllers is to

1. Have a property on the root scope
2. Update that property on the root scope
3. Broadcast the fact that the property was updated
4. All children scopes that need to know , will listen for the broadcast.

as opposed to expose an object on a Service and letting angular's two way databinding do all the heavy lifting. Why would anyone go with the 'root scope publish/subscribe' methodology, instead of exposing an object on the service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's interesting question.

First we should consider differences on various levels:

- Scope

  - in case of `$rootScope` we define variable in global scope
  - in case of shared services we can inject this service to controllers that really use this value
- Extensibility

  - `$rootScope` - we have limited options to add additional logic to work on this value (we can define another global function)
  - shared services - we are free to define any kind of logic
- Encapsulation

  - `$rootScope` - all object defined in $rootScope would be visible in all modules
  - shared services - we can decide what is visible and what is not
- Modularity

  - `$rootScope` - global variables is not places in module spaces
  - shared services - service is a separate module for application
- Maintaining

  - `$rootScope` - it's very hard to find which components use our `$rootScope` variable.
  - shared services - we can see which services we use and we can find in which component we use this service
- Binding

  - `$rootScope` - it is easy to setup two-way binding in several controllers on one variable in `$rootScope`
  - shared services - could be tricky to enable two-way binding

In my opinion this is only useful for make really global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have two controllers A and B, and a service S, storing the common data.

When A changes data in S, B cannot directly change its scope value by understanding that data in S has changed. Someone has to say to it that data in S has changed and update its scope according to this change. This may be done two ways.

- One is rootScope broadcast: service S broadcast changes and B listens this broadcast.
- The other $scope.$watch: In controller B, scope must watch the changes in service data.

Comment: What about passing by reference? `ctrl.data = srv.data` . If you use `angular.copy` to keep the reference alive, every time you update the data on the service, all controllers will be in sync with that service data.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which kind of data you are managing, if you are for example relying on a DB where you perform CRUD actions, you'd like a service to just interact with the DB.

That's called a stateless service, some people vouch for it and some are against and prefer to have state also on the service, exposing the object as you mentioned.

I'll leave you a couple resources with more information on the topic so you can decide which solution suits you best

http://www.johnpapa.net/sharing-data-in-an-angular-controller-or-an-angular-service/

http://www.webdeveasy.com/angularjs-data-model/