# Hold data between pages in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js.Please suggest which one is better . I have a page where I can select a no of check boxes and navigate to 2 nd page.I want to show the checked values when I press back button in browser.
Which one is better using $rootScope or stateparam or localstorage.Please consider performance also.

Comment: Please, search before ask.. there are a lot of questions answered like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410484/angular-use-root-scope-vs-services-to-share-data

Comment: I think OP's question is somewhat different; localStorage vs $rootScope are very different things. But, tldr, you should use scope unless you want semi-permanence of localStorage (having state persist in new tabs, next day, etc). So, the answers to that developer033's link are good answers. Perf will be fine in either case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Going through your options one by one:**

1. `$rootScope`: You should try to avoid using this option as it is associated to the global state. Use this option only if you want the data you set to be *globally* available throughout the app and do not want to reuse the same variable names anywhere else.
2. `$stateParams`: These typically go into the state URI as [a dynamic part](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#basic-parameters) of the whole URL. This has only limited usage, and may not be a good idea for your use case where you need to store data from multiple checkboxes.
3. `localStorage`: This is slower than using a JavaScript variable, and hence [not a good idea](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/top-10-mistakes-angularjs-developers-make).

**Services:**

Here is a better solution for you, entirely within the AngularJS paradigm: [AngularJS services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

*Excerpt from the link in point 3:*

> Data should also be stored in services, except where it is being bound
>   to the `$scope`. Services are singletons that persist throughout the
>   lifetime of the application, while controllers are transient between
>   application states. If data is stored in the controller then it will
>   need to be fetched from somewhere when it is reinstantiated. Even if
>   the data is stored in `localStorage`, it's an order of magnitude slower
>   to retrieve than from with a Javascript variable.

You can use the service to set and get your data inside your controller anywhere in the app in a consistent manner.

**Here is an indicative example:**

```
app.factory('formDetails', formDetails);

function formDetails() {
    var formData = {};    
    return {
        getProperty: function () {
            return formData;
        },
        setProperty: function(values) {
            formData = values;
        }
    };
};
```

**Use it in your controller as:**

```
app.controller('MyController', [ '$scope', 'formDetails' , function($scope, formDetails) {
    $scope.checkboxData = {};

    // on load call service 'get' function
    $scope.checkboxData = formDetails.getProperty();

    // on some event/watch function call service 'set' function
    formDetails.setProperty($scope.checkboxData);

}]);
```