# AngularJS (with Material) and data exchange between controllers - $rootScope, factory or service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm new to AngularJS (currently using 1.6.5) and I'm trying to figure out how to split code from one big controller into couple small controllers which will exchange data between themselves.

In a few words I have the logic to register attendees, register contact person and then credit card capture informations in one large controller (let's call it `RegistrationCtrl`) as all captured data from those three steps are passed further as the JSON object. My goal is to split that big controller into three separate. Side note - for the attendees registration I'm using `mdDialog` from AngularJS Material.

I have done some research and I have found multiple ways to do that by using `$rootScope` or factory, or service.

For the service scenario I thought it is good to share access to the data between controllers like DB or REST API calls somewhere else but not to exchange captured data on a local level between controllers.

`$rootScope` I'm using in the `MainCtrl` controller to store data from the DB which I have got via service.

As there are three different ways to handle desired functionality which one I should to choose to have it used in the most efficient way (and will work with AngularJS Material)?

I'm kind of stuck on a decision which one way I should to go. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410484/angular-use-root-scope-vs-services-to-share-data/35411623#35411623

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is a bit too broad, and, frankly, opinionated.  *my opinion* is that using `$rootScope` is a major anti-pattern.  Factories and Services are very similar, as they are both Providers;  the choice of a Factory or Service comes down to understanding the difference between the two in relation to your data.

Comment: @Claies can you suggest some site which explains that matter (_Factory or Service comes down to understanding the difference between the two in relation to your data_)