# AngularJS - moving Material mdDialog to service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm trying to cleanup code of one of my controllers which became too big. First I have decided to move attendee registration, which uses AngularJS Material mdDialog, to the service.

Original (and working) controller code looks like:

```
myApp.controller('RegistrationController', ['$scope','$routeParams','$rootScope','$location','$filter','$mdDialog', function($scope, $routeParams, $rootScope, $location, $filter, $mdDialog){

    var attendee = this;
    attendees = [];
...

    $scope.addAttendee = function(ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        templateUrl: 'views/regForm.tmpl.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose:true,
        controllerAs: 'attendee',
        fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen, // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
        locals: {parent: $scope}
    })
    .then(function(response){
        attendees.push(response);

        console.log(attendees);
        console.log(attendees.length);
    })
  };

    function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {

        var attendee = this;

        $scope.hide = function() {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
        };

        $scope.save = function(response) {
            $mdDialog.hide(response);
        };
    }

}]);
```

and the code for the controller after separation:

```
myApp.controller('RegistrationController', ['$scope','$routeParams','$rootScope','$location','$filter','$mdDialog','Attendees', function($scope, $routeParams, $rootScope, $location, $filter, $mdDialog, Attendees){

...


    $scope.attendees= Attendees.list();

    $scope.addAttendee = function (ev) {
        Attendees.add(ev);
    }

    $scope.deleteAttendee = function (id) {
        Attendees.delete(id);
    }

}]);
```

New service code looks like:

```
myApp.service('Attendees', ['$mdDialog', function ($mdDialog) {
    //to create unique attendee id
    var uid = 1;

    //attendees array to hold list of all attendees
    var attendees = [{
        id: 0,
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        phone: ""
    }];

    //add method create a new attendee
    this.add = function(ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        templateUrl: 'views/regForm.tmpl.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose:true,
        controllerAs: 'attendee',
        fullscreen: this.customFullscreen, // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
        //locals: {parent: $scope}
    })
    .then(function(response){
        attendees.push(response);

        console.log(attendees);
        console.log(attendees.length);
    })
  };

    //simply search attendees list for given id
    //and returns the attendee object if found
    this.get = function (id) {
        for (i in attendees) {
            if (attendees[i].id == id) {
                return attendees[i];
            }
        }

    }

    //iterate through attendees list and delete 
    //attendee if found
    this.delete = function (id) {
        for (i in attendees) {
            if (attendees[i].id == id) {
                attendees.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    //simply returns the attendees list
    this.list = function () {
        return attendees;
    }

    function DialogController($mdDialog) {

        this.hide = function() {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };

        this.cancel = function() {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
        };

        this.save = function(response) {
            $mdDialog.hide(response);
        };
    }

}]);
```

but I'm not able to "save" from the spawned mdDialog box which uses `ng-click=save(attendee)` neither close the dialog box.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr). This error occurred  in this case because the code attempted to inject a scope object into something that's not a controller or a directive.

Comment: In the controller, some objects are on the `this` context and some on `$scope`.Is there a specific reason for mixing these two paradigms?

Comment: @georgeawg I have cleaned the code and updated OP

Comment: Hello Jack i see still have trouble with your mdDialog.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco Yeah - it works fine when I keep it in the controller but the code became too big so I have decided to move it to the service where is not working as I have expected

Comment: why you move to a service... ???, why just dont create another file with dialogcontroller content. ?? ... the goal for a service is that in can be injectable in anywhere of any controller do you have. if thats the goal. you need to do some improvements.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco It is related to my other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693921/angularjs-with-material-and-data-exchange-between-controllers-rootscope-fa Simple my current knowledge of AngularJS is not sufficient to do right choice to clear that code in a proper way :) You can answer to that other question with your suggestions.

Comment: i see i would recomend to see the concepts definitions. for this example if you want the mdDialog be more generic an be reutilizable for other intances in other contollers its better in a service, if not just create a new file an put its logic.

Comment: if you still want to be in a service, you need to define the methods, save, delete, get, properly,  its better be an a promise your methods . example.....    mdDialogService.save($scope).then(function(response){ console.log(response)}, function(reject){ });

Comment: in your service you need have a method save. whou returns a promise

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151981/discussion-between-jacktheknife-and-jesus-carrasco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not able to "save" from the spawned mdDialog box which uses `ng-click=save(attendee)` neither close the dialog box.

When instantiating a controller with "controllerAs" syntax, use the name with which it is instantiated:

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.save(ctrl.attendee)">Save</button>
```

```
this.add = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
    controller: DialogController,
    templateUrl: 'views/regForm.tmpl.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose:true,
    controllerAs:  ̶'̶a̶t̶t̶e̶n̶d̶e̶e̶'̶ 'ctrl',
    fullscreen: this.customFullscreen, // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
    //locals: {parent: $scope}
})
.then(function(response){
    attendees.push(response);

    console.log(attendees);
    console.log(attendees.length);
    return response;     
});
```

To avoid confusion, choose a controller instance name that is different from the data names.

Comment: I have updated code and related `templateUrl`view with the `ctrl` and dialog box works as should.

Comment: One more question - when I try to access `$scope.attendees = Attendees.list();` in the controller it seems to be empty

Comment: To avoid confusion, choose a service name that is different than the data names.

Answer (score 0):

$scope is not available to be injected into a service when it's created. You need to refactor the service and its methods so that you don't inject $scope into it and instead pass the current scope to the service methods when you call them.

I actually have a notification module that I inject which uses $mdDialog. Below is the code for it. Perhaps it will help.

```
(() => {
    "use strict";
    class notification {
        constructor($mdToast, $mdDialog, $state) {
            /* @ngInject */
            this.toast = $mdToast
            this.dialog = $mdDialog
            this.state = $state

            /* properties */
            this.transitioning = false
            this.working = false
        }
        openHelp() {
            this.showAlert({
                "title": "Help",
                "textContent": `Help is on the way for ${this.state.current.name}!`,
                "ok": "OK"
            })
        }
        showAlert(options) {
            if (angular.isString(options)) {
                var text = angular.copy(options)
                options = {}
                options.textContent = text
                options.title = " "
            }
            if (!options.ok) {
                options.ok = "OK"
            }
            if (!options.clickOutsideToClose) {
                options.clickOutsideToClose = true
            }
            if (!options.ariaLabel) {
                options.ariaLabel = 'Alert'
            }
            if (!options.title) {
                options.title = "Alert"
            }
            return this.dialog.show(this.dialog.alert(options))
        }
        showConfirm(options) {
            if (angular.isString(options)) {
                var text = angular.copy(options)
                options = {}
                options.textContent = text
                options.title = " "
            }
            if (!options.ok) {
                options.ok = "OK"
            }
            if (!options.cancel) {
                options.cancel = "Cancel"
            }
            if (!options.clickOutsideToClose) {
                options.clickOutsideToClose = false
            }
            if (!options.ariaLabel) {
                options.ariaLabel = 'Confirm'
            }
            if (!options.title) {
                options.title = "Confirm"
            }
            return this.dialog.show(this.dialog.confirm(options))
        }
        showToast(toastMessage, position) {
            if (!position) { position = 'top' }
            return this.toast.show(this.toast.simple()
                .content(toastMessage)
                .position(position)
                .action('OK'))
        }
        showYesNo(options) {
            options.ok = "Yes"
            options.cancel = "No"
            return this.showConfirm(options)
        }
        uc() {
            return this.showAlert({
                htmlContent: "<img src='img\\underconstruction.jpg'>",
                ok: "OK",
                title: "Under Construction"
            })
        }

    }
    notification.$inject = ['$mdToast', '$mdDialog', '$state']
    angular.module('NOTIFICATION', []).factory("notification", notification)
})()
```

Then inject notification (lower case) into my controllers in order to utilize it. I store notification in a property of the controller and then call it with something like this:

```
this.notification.showYesNo({
                    clickOutsideToClose: true,
                    title: 'Delete Customer Setup?',
                    htmlContent: `Are you sure you want to Permanently Delete the Customer Setup for ${custLabel}?`,
                    ariaLabel: 'Delete Dialog'
                }).then(() => { ...
                    this.notification.working = true
                    this.ezo.EDI_CUSTOMER.remove(this.currentId).then(() => {
                        this.primaryTab = 0
                        this.removeCustomerFromList(this.currentId)
                        this.currentId = 0
                        this.notification.working = false
                    }, error => {
                        this.notification.working = false
                        this.notification.showAlert({
                            title: "Error",
                            htmlContent: error
                        })

                    })
```

Comment: Some kind of an example will be helpful.

Comment: Actually, I read George's comment and thought that was the case. I don't see references to $scope in the service. "Unable to save" doesn't tell us anything. What happens?

Comment: Well - it looks like controller declared for `$mdDialog` as `controller: DialogController,` is not working as it should (hide, cancel and save). In that case I'm not sure if it is possible to move `mdDialog` to the service.

Comment: I actually use $mdDialog in a service, so it's definitely possible.